# Aws S3 hosted angular application - when calling api url it amends s3 bucket url to that

Tags: angularjs, angular, amazon-s3, cloud-hosting

I have a aws s3 bucket hosted angularjs application. All build static files are hosted there in s3 bucket. When that application call the back end api url it amends the s3 bucket url to the front and it fails the api call entirely.

Ex: if original api url **http://example.org/** then it amend the s3 bucket url to  that so it appears like: **http:///example.org/**

Can anyone help me to figure it out why it happens.

Comment: Can you show your code where you're running the fetch?

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJS? They are two different frameworks.